# Naming split data frames within for loop

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame with 10000 row and I want to divide this data frame into 10 different data frames with first 1000 rows in first df next 1000 in second df. However I want to do this using for loop.

`df = pd.DataFrame(range(0,10000))`

using for loop I want to divide this in to 10 df with name df1,df2,df3....df10
I want to name them in the for-loop iteratively

Is there any way I can do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import math

start = 0; chunkSize = 100
chunkNo = math.ceil(df.index.size / chunkSize)
for n in range(1, chunkNo + 1):
    varName = f'df{n}'
    endNo = start + chunkSize
    globals()[varName] = df.iloc[start : endNo]
    print(f'Created: {varName}, rows [ {start:4} : {endNo:4} )')
    start += chunkSize
```

It is a "dirty trick" to create a variable passing its name as a string,
but at least it leads to the expected result.

Now print *df1*, *df2*, ... to check the result.